# How to restore pretrained model to initialize parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have downloaded an network with its pretrained model. I added several layers and parameters to the network, I want to use this pretrained model to initialize the original parameters,and random initialize new added parameters by myself.I use this code:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, "output/saver-test")
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
```

but I met the error:"Key global_step not found in checkpoint",this error because I have some new parameters that didn't exist in pretrained model.But how can I solve this problem? What's more,I want to use this code   "sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())" to initialize the new added parameters,but the extracted parameters from pretrained model will be covered by it?

Comment: Do you know which variables are new and which are to be restored? If so, you can pass a `list` or a `dict` to the saver to specify them (see documentation for [`Saver` constructor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#__init__), parameter `var_list`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because of your network is not perfectly match to the loaded one.
You can use selective checkpoint loader something like that:

```
  reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader(os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, ckpt_name))
    restore_dict = dict()
    for v in tf.trainable_variables():
        tensor_name = v.name.split(':')[0]
        if reader.has_tensor(tensor_name):
            print('has tensor ', tensor_name)
            restore_dict[tensor_name] = v

    restore_dict['my_new_var_scope/my_new_var'] = self.get_my_new_var_variable()
```

Where get_my_new_var_variable() is something like that:

```
    def get_my_new_var_variable(self):
    with tf.variable_scope("my_new_var_scope",reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        my_new_var = tf.get_variable("my_new_var", dtype=tf.int32,initializer=tf.constant([23, 42]))
    return my_new_var
```

Loading the weights:

```
self.saver = tf.train.Saver(restore_dict)
    self.saver.restore(self.sess, os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, ckpt_name))
```

Edited:

Note that in order to avoid override the loaded variables you can use this method:

```
def initialize_uninitialized(sess):
  global_vars = tf.global_variables()
  is_not_initialized = sess.run([tf.is_variable_initialized(var) for var in global_vars])
  not_initialized_vars = [v for (v, f) in zip(global_vars, is_not_initialized) if not f]
  if len(not_initialized_vars):
    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(not_initialized_vars))
```

Or simply calling `tf.global_variables_initializer()` before loading the variables should work here.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have tried your codes,you created a dict "restore_dict" to store trainable variables,but I still don't know how to "feed" it to my new var scope,can you help me? thanks.

Comment: @zhaowu What do you mean by feeding variables into scope? Please share the relevant part of your code or try to rephrase what you are trying to do here...
I suggested a workaround to load only subset of the variables so you can add to the restore_dict new variable with your initialization.

Comment: @ Idan azuri, Yes,I tried what you suggest and succeed.But I have another question,before "saver.restore(sess, "output/saver-test")",I should use "sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())" to initialize all the variables,does it means the old variables were assigned twice?

Comment: @zhaowu , that is correct. Just change the order, call 'f.global_variables_initializer()' and only then load the variables.
Also, you can initialized the uninitialized variables like I wrote in my comment (edited)

Comment: You solved my problem,thank you very much.By the way,Can I  invite  you for this question? I'm so grateful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52565964/valueerror-variable-conv-w-already-exists-disallowed