# ValueError: Variable conv/W already exists, disallowed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was using TensorFlow and encountered an error. I want to use `"conv_W[0]"`  to initialize `"conv/W"`, they have the same shape of [3,3,192,32]. My code is as follows:

```
def convolutional(X,reuse = reuse):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope or 'conv', reuse=reuse):
        W = tf.get_variable("W", shape=[3,3,192,32])  
----------------------------------------------------------------------

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    conv_w = tf.get_variable('conv/W', initializer=tf.constant_initializer(conv_W[0]))
```

The error is `"ValueError: Variable conv/W already exists, disallowed.Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:"`

Answer (score 0):

That's probably happening because you initalize the variable on every epoch, so in other words the error means: Do you want to share this variable or you want to redeclare it?
Since the desired behavior is unclear (create new variables or reuse the existing ones?) TensorFlow will fail.
If you do want to share the variable you can just change the line:

```
conv_w = tf.get_variable('conv/W', initializer=tf.constant_initializer(conv_W[0]),reuse=True)
```

Otherwise set `reuse=False`, and that will solve your problem.

For more information about how to share/unshare variables see the [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variables):